# Can Openears output an audio sound file after recognition?

Tags: xcode, openears

I am studying Openears and I have a problem on it.

I am making an app with voice recognition features and I need to ensure the output after recognition is a saved .wav file (For example: When I say something, There will be ringing 
sound after recognition).

Can someone tell me if Openears can do it and how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

OpenEars developer here. This is outside of OpenEars' API since it isn't intended to be a general-purpose audio toolkit, but you can just play back a WAV using AVAudioPlayer after receiving a hypothesis. If you'd like further assistance from me getting that working please bring your question to the OpenEars forum.